# Convert systimestamp to dd-mon-yyyy

Tags: oracle

There may be lot of duplicate  of this but i  am facing typical issue where i am saving data usign systimestamp one example is data stored is of this `27-MAY-13 09.00.39.169849000 AM -04:00`

I want to retrive this data in dd-mon-yyyy format i am using following query to do that

`TO_DATE(TRUNC( DATE_COLUMN),'dd-mon-yyyy') from sometable`  i am getting result as below 
25-MAR-13

but i want it as 25-MAR-2013 can anyone help my db is oracle 11g or 10g not sure

@cade

i have a small problem i cannot use the query as you said , as i am having subquery sql outllook goes like this

```
   WITH C AS (
select 
  rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, TRIM(VALUE_TX) || '#')  order by field_id ).extract ('//text()'), ',') somedat, 
  date_colum
FROM (
SELECT form some table)  
   select First_Name as "First Name",Last_Name as "Last Name",EMAIL,Mobile_Phone as "Mobile Phone",Submitted as "Submitted On"

   from (
   SELECT SUBSTR(c.somedat,0,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,1)-1) AS First_Name,
    SUBSTR(c.somedata,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,1)+1,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,2)-INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,1)-1) AS Last_Name,
    SUBSTR(c.somedata,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,2)+1,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,3)-INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,2)-1) AS Mobile_Phone,
    SUBSTR(c.somedata,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,3)+1,INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,4)-INSTR(c.somedata,'#',1,3)-1) AS EMAIL
    to_char(TRUNC( C.date_colum),'dd-mon-yyyy')         AS Submitted

    FROM C)
   order by 5 asc
```

Comment: I can't see your problem, you can select `date_colum` in the subquery and in the outer select use `to_char` and in the outer order by `trunc` (don't use `order by 5` it's bad practice anyway). Another option can be to have 2 columns in the subquery select - one with to_char and one with trunc

Answer (score 3):

A date / timestamp in oracle always contain a time part.
You can use the TRUNC function to make the time `00:00:00`.

A date / timestamp in oracle NEVER contains a format, it's a number representing the date and time.
You cannot use to_date function on a date since it accepts a string and not a date. If you do then oracle will implicitly convert the date to a varchar2 according to NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

So, when you just want a date and ignore the time part (i.e. in the order by clause) use `trunc` on the date / timestamp column.
When you want to display it (i.e. in the select clause) use the `to_char` function

Your query can look like this:

```
 SELECT to_char(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-MON-yyyy') 
 FROM SOMETABLE
 ORDER BY trunc(DATE_COLUMN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You an try:

```
select to_char(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-mon-yyyy') from SOMETABLE
```

Please check if it works. I don't have an oracle DB around to play with :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-mon-yyyy') FROM SOMETABLE;
```

This will give output as `25-MAR-2013.`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select to_char(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-MON-yyyy') from SOMETABLE ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b9785/8)

Comment: No need for the `upper` function, if you want the month in uppercase then use `MON` instead of `mon`

Comment: I want it as date so i have to use TO_DATE

Comment: I mean to say i need date data as date because if am usign order by clause on it if i use to_char then it will treated as varchar column hence i cant order by

Comment: Please see my update answere i have slit issue in using order by clause the comment starts from @cade

Comment: SOrry i think i was too exited the issue is not solved can anyone help me please

Comment: AnyOne Can help me with this please

Comment: @Ashwin, as far as i understand, you want to sort the result based on the date. So as @cade suggested, use `to_char(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-MON-yyyy')` in your SELECT clause and use `trunc(DATE_COLUMN,'d')` in the ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_COLUMN,'dd-mon-yyyy') FROM SOMETABLE;
```

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and those already proposed?

Comment: No solution yet can anyone help